# Performance in one line assign variables

Tags: c#

Recently, I started work on a new project and in the code almost everywhere when assign value to variable we use assign a few variables in one line. Some example:

```
object foo;
double bar;

foo = bar = 100;
```

Our team leader says that it will more performance instead of

```
foo = 100;
bar = 100;
```

but why? The code is more readable in the second case.

Can anybody explain me why?

P.S. Team Leader doesn't know why, but know that is more performance :\

Comment: Ask your team leader for concrete performance evidence, not only that it makes a difference, but that the difference is *significant* in your app. Unless your TL also claims the first form is more readable (which I'd certainly disagree with), they should be providing justification for making the code less readable.

Comment: Premature optimization? If **that** changes anything I'd be surprised.

Comment: I don't think there is any performance hit, moreover in first one if one is working with git or any other repository, it will hard to locate merge conflicts.

Comment: @JonSkeet Team Leader doesn't know why, but know that is more performance :\. I like such guys :)

Comment: Get him to prove it ..

Comment: Other guy says that it something with boxing and I need to see IL code to understand. But I do not have experience with IL :(

Comment: It's not up to you to prove it - readability simply should not be hurt for vague "Well, I've heard somewhere that it might have an effect."

Comment: Just tried it on [Try Roslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) - it's almost identical.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JonSkeet.  Can you convert your comment into answer? I want to show that to my TL. Thanks

Comment: You can show your TL it as a comment. It wouldn't really be an answer to your question.

Comment: If he is too keen in performance, not sure why he have kept `foo` as type `object` rather than `double` to avoid boxing! I would have combined declaration and assignment together wherever possible - `double foo = 100; double bar = 100;`. _Other guy says that it something with boxing_ - I dont think you could "escape" boxing in this manner - If Im not wrong, `foo = bar = 100;` - this would box to double, where `foo= 100` will box to int - again gotta check the IL to confirm

Comment: @JonSkeet there is a semantic difference between the two. One gives you a boxed `double`, the other a boxed `int`. Not that it has any performance implication but the semantics change completely. @Manfred Radlwimmer

Comment: @InBetween: Yes, that's a good point - and the kind of thing that the TL should be justifying as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two proposed code snippets are absolutely *not* the same, although it has very little to do with performance. There is a very big semantic difference in one program and the other.

`foo = bar = 100` will end up with a boxed `double`. `foo = 100; bar = 100;` will end up with a boxed `int`. That is semantically a *big* difference. If later on a code expecting a boxed `double` attempts to unbox it via an explicit cast, `(double)boxed`, the application will crash if the latter option is used.